# Set of links opening up in another tab in browser

Tags: html

I have a resource called Artists, that is connected to a table called artists.  For the view, `/artists`, I run through the table using a foreach loop to display some of the information.  I create links, like so:

```
<div class="boxxy">
<a href="/artists/{{$artist->id}}" target="_blank" class="anchor-hover">
            <img src="{{ $artist->image_path}}" alt="{{$artist->stage_name}}" height="200" width="200">
            <span class="details">
                <h2>{{$artist->stage_name}}</h2>
                <p class="desc">{{$artist->description}}</p>
                <span class="pupdate">{{ $artist->city}}, {{ $artist->state}}</span>
                <span class="viewlink">Play My City</span>
            </span>
            </a>
</div>
```

However, using this, when I click on the image, it takes me to another tab in the browser (to the correct place, like `artists/7`, but in a different tab).  My question is, how do I prevent the page from being opened up in another tab?  I would like it just directed in the same tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `target="_blank"` in your `a`nchor.